# Quarto: embed html iframe in pptx

Tags: quarto

I am having a problem here. I run an analysis and exported a plotly figure as html using htmlwidgets::savewidget(). Now I want to import that in quarto. I used iframe like:

```
<iframe src="plot.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This works with revealjs but not pptx. Any workarounds here?

Here is my header

```
---
title: "Presentation"
format:
    pptx: default
scrollable: false
slide-number: true
embed-resources: true
date: today
---
```

Thank you